# electron react boilerplate access resource in mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, electron

I have assets, and when I package them, I add them to the extraResources as well. However, when I try to get the path of the assets folder using process.resourcesPath, it gives me the wrong path. It provides the project folder path instead of the installed application path

"pathtoproject/release/build/mac/TestApp.app/Contents/Resources"

This is working well development environment and I am using latest [electron react boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

```
const { sourcefile, filename } = data;
const videoPath = app.getPath('exe');
const pathSep = path.sep;
let source;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  source = path.join('assets', 'videos', sourcefile);
} else {
  source = path.join(
    process.resourcesPath,
    'app.asar',
    'assets',
    'videos',
    sourcefile,
  );
}
const pth = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), filename);
console.log(source, pth);
const res = fs.copyFileSync(source, pth);
return { result: res };
```